# Getting Characetr encoding error in django Incorrect string value: '\\xF0\\x9F\\x

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, character-encoding

I getting this error

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1366, "Incorrect string value:
>   '\xF0\x9F\x99\x8F \xF0...' for column 'html_code' at row 1")

I created database using this command

`CREATE DATABASE sample CHARACTER SET utf8;`

I have these settings in mysql

```
vim /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf
[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

vim /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

I even used this command as well

```
ALTER TABLE sample_randy CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8
```

The problem is it worked first time i use those command and after sometime it again stop working with same error.

I am not sure which thing is resetting the options

If i delete the database, create again and run script again then it work again. if i rerun again then it get same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the character for 'PERSON WITH FOLDED HANDS', you needed utf8mb4 (not just utf8) everywhere.  Do

```
ALTER TABLE sample_randy CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
```